# Room equivalent to @Configuration annotation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I'm ussing room in android app, and I want to save some data when the database is created on the device. how can achieve this? I want to use something like the @Configuration annotation that you can find in spring.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate I find this, but I think is to much for wath I want, I only need to insert one or two entries with normal info